# Find/Replace content in CSS pseudo-elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

Trying to find some text that is content produced by a ":before" pseudo-element.

And then I would like to change the css of that content.

Is this even possible? Here's what I have.

Thanks.

```js
var $test = $('.test').html();
$test = $test.replace(/one/gi, '<span class="red">one</span>');
$test = $test.replace(/two/gi, '<span class="green">two</span>');
$test = $test.replace(/three/gi, '<span class="blue">three</span>');
$('.test').html($test);
```

```css
.test:before { content: 'one two three';}

.red {color: red;}
.green {color: green;}
.blue {color: blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test"></div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/postcolonialboy/z5nLmt48/8/).

Comment: you cannot place html inside content of pseudo element

Comment: What's wrong with adding the class the the element itself and then styling its `:before` pseudo-element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to *replace* the content with some html elements. You can try this way

```js
var $test = $('.test');

// clear :before content data
$test.attr('data-before', '');

$test.append('<span class="red">one</span>');
$test.append('<span class="green">two</span>');
$test.append('<span class="blue">three</span>');
```

```css
.test:before { content: attr(data-before);}

.red {color: red;}
.green {color: green;}
.blue {color: blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test" data-before="one two three"></div>
```

It seems to be *hacked*. Because we don't really *replace* anything, just show and hide the content.

Answer (score 0):

Get please use

```
#app::before { content: 'hello world!' }

var myIdElement = document.getElementById("app");
var beforeStyle = window.getComputedStyle(myIdElement, ":before");

console.log(beforeStyle.content) // hello world!
```

Set please use

```
<div id="app" data-text="hello world!"></div>

#app::before { content: attr(data-text) }

document.getElementById("app").setAttribute('data-text','new text')
```